# Python: Iterate over string with while loop

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I'm trying to delete all the characters at the end of a string following the last occurrence of a '+'. So for instance, if my string is 'Mother+why+is+the+river+laughing' I want to reduce this to 'Mother+why+is+the+river'. I don't know what the string will be in advance though.

I thought of iterating backwards over the string. Something like:

```
while letter in my_string[::-1] != '+':
    my_string = my_string[:-1]
```

This won't work because letter in not pre defined.

Any thoughts?

Comment: to quickly answer your question, you don't need `letter` : `while my_string[-1] != '+':` is sufficient. rfind and rsplit based answers are better, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
my_string = my_string.rsplit('+', 1)[0]
```

`.rsplit()` splits from the *end* of a string; with a limit of 1 it'll only split on the very last `+` in the string and `[0]` gives you everything before that last `+`.

Demo:

```
>>> 'Mother+why+is+the+river+laughing'.rsplit('+', 1)[0]
'Mother+why+is+the+river'
```

If there is *no* `+` in the string, the original string is returned:

```
>>> 'Mother'.rsplit('+', 1)[0]
'Mother'
```

As for your loop; you are testing against a reversed string and the condition returns `True` until the last `+` has been removed; you'd have to test *in the loop* for what character you just removed:

```
while True:
    last = my_string[-1]
    my_string = my_string[:-1]
    if last == '+':
        break
```

but this is rather inefficient compared to using `str.rsplit()`; creating a new string for each character removed is costly.